# discrete-deterministic models or f-schemes matlab

Tags: matlab

Please help me with the problem of how to solve it in matlab using Chart?
There are three computers working in the local computer network. At regular intervals (after a month), all computers are tested, as a result of which each is recognized as either serviceable or requiring repair. Using the data in the figure, determine the probability distribution in a year.
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEvsV.png)

I don't understand how to do this. Why are there 3 states written and there are 4 of them in the image&

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the chart in the figure has 4 states, not 3.

Comment: therefore would it be reasonable to assume that the chart is a program that runs in all 3 computers for 1 month?

Comment: please confirm, if a computer ends up in state S0 this may mean 'service required' and if on testing the state is S1 S2 S3 it may mean 'no service required'?